# Axios catch interrupted requests like refreshing a page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Does anyone know how to catch an interrupted ajax requests?

any event or user actions that would interrupt a request before it receives a response.

cause I'm having this weird behavior in a webview where it catches an error on the .catch() every time I refresh a page that a request haven't receive a response yet.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the answer its just

```
}).catch(err => {
    if (err.message == 'Network Error') {
        //
    }
});
```